# How to mic mute when recording video?

Tags: android, media, microphone, android-developer-api

How to mute mic in android my code is working but in some device mic is not muted please give solution my code is:

```
private void setMicMuted(boolean state){
    AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager)con.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    // get the working mode and keep it
    int workingAudioMode = myAudioManager.getMode();

    myAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);

    // change mic state only if needed
    if (myAudioManager.isMicrophoneMute() != state) {
        myAudioManager.setMicrophoneMute(state);
    }

    // set back the original working mode
    myAudioManager.setMode(workingAudioMode); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MediaRecorder just use it without calling setAudio on it, this way it will only record video without audio.

Comment: i am not using media recorder